# Problema con funciones y $.post ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, function

no encontre una mejor forma de formular la pregunta pero el problema es sencillo.
Tengo una funcion en mi jquery donde envio un id y por medio de php verifico si existe o no relaciones con ese id. Tengo una variable la cual le asigno por defecto true y si no existe ninguna relación esa variable se torna en false, luego por medio del return, devuelvo ese resultado booleano.

El problema, que creo que es de contexto, es que siempre devuelve el valor por defecto sin importar el resultado del $.post. Primero intente que el return este dentro del $.post, pero en otra funcion donde necesito el return, me daba indefinida. Ahora solo me devuelve true, si en cambio de true le asigno cualquier otro valor, devuelve ese valor y no lo que necesito. A continuacion dejo primero un fragmento de la funcion (funcion A) donde llamo a la funcion con problemas (funcion B)

```
let control = base_control($(e.currentTarget).data('id')); //llamo a la funcion B
        console.log(control);
        if(control === true){
            alertify.alert('Hay sabores que contienen esta base, por favor, elimine o editelos antes de eliminar la base.');
            
        }else{
           /*fragmento de codigo */
       
        }

 /*Empieza la funcion B */
  function base_control(id){
    alert(id);
    let conf = true;
    const postData ={
        id 
    }
    $.post('../../model/bases/control_base_sabor.php', postData, function(response){
        console.log(response)
        let data = JSON.parse(response);
        if(data.estado !=1 ){
            conf = false;
        }
    }). catch (error =>{
        console.log(error);
    })

    return conf;
}
```

ya checkie si existe problemas con el id que envio o si hay algo mal en el archivo php, pero todo se envia de forma correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Si te molesta $.post() usa mejor $.ajax()

Este último es

$.ajax({
url:'',
data:objeto_que_quieres_enviar,
type:'post',
})
.done(function (response) {})